# present continuous for a short action is it possible in this case

Tags: tense, present-continuous

After waking up today I received a phone call of a friend I had not seen or spoken for years .

Can I say: "my day **is starting** very well" or "my day **has started** well" or "my day **starts** well"

I think the first solution is the best because it is not a habit (no present) and this is what is happening now so present continuous seems to be the best . But can we consider a start as something in progress?
What about present perfect and present  in this case.

Comment: If it's still early morning you can say that the day _is starting well_, (it's still 'the start of the day'). A bit later you might say that it _has started well_.

Comment: the difference between present perfect and present continuous is only a difference of time

Comment: A common usage, especially in greetings, is "[my day is] **going** well." (Thus, "How's it going?" can be a greeting, meaning "How good is everything about your situation right now?") "It's going well" can have a very generic attitude toward time: You could mean your day, your week, your month, or even your year. If you want to mix this generic sense with a reference to the present moment you could say "My day is going well **so far**."